# django add 'http' when redirect after main url

Tags: python, django

i have web example.com

and i  use @login_required in views.

If user not authenticated, browser redirect to:http://example.com**http**/accounts/login/

I don't know why.
On my home laptop all working good. But on the production i see that.

Do you have some ideas?

I'm using nginx with uwsgi.

```
     @login_required
     def callshistory(request):
            all_user_history=[]
            gates=[]
           _user = request.user.username
```

Comment: What is the value of `LOGIN_URL` and `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` settings?

Comment: Please post your `settings.py` that you are using in production.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see LOGIN_URL in your settings listing. Are you sure it's really declared in your case?

From django source:

```
resolved_login_url = force_str(resolve_url(login_url or settings.LOGIN_URL))
...
```

login_url argument is process same way as settings var

Comment: yes, i'm sure because redirect is happens but with unexpected''http"

Comment: I tries use LOGIN_URL='hrh'  in settins. Same result http://mysite.comhttp/hrh/?next=http%3A//mysite.com/